# Download and replace sqlite database on mobile device

Tags: jquery, database, sqlite, mobile

I made an app using jQuery using an existing sqlite database. Then phonegapp created the app for all mobile platforms. My question is can i periodically download a newly database and replace the older one which is on the mobile device? how can this be done? is there any issue because of different platform?